# Storage "Server" with HDDs that can be accessed by Servers in Cluster

Tags: storage, cluster

I want to setup some Servers that only have a small amount of Disk Space that is necessary for Linux and Software. All these should act as a Cluster. How would I go about adding sort of like a Storage Server that includes like 8 HDDs with about 2 TB each, that can be accessed by all the Servers in the Cluster? (Amount of HDDs and Space doesn't really matter, only the function of it) I'm sorry im not a System Engineer or anything but I'm still interested in building something like this and don't know where and how to find something like this out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post is very unclear and not very specific. It also contain several questions. But I will try to give you some pointers where you can start to look.

The first one is how you should handle the storage at the storage server. If you want to have a single namespace for the whole amount of disk space it would be easier to have some sort of raid solution. This could also be good for data integrity or data availability (or both) depending on what raid level you choose.

There is multiple ways to implement raid (both in hardware and software) so you need to investigate what suits your needs. If you want to have it simple I would recommend some sort of software raid that doesn't require any specific hardware to start with.

The other question is how you will share this data among the cluster nodes. The simplest way to do this is probably by setting up a NFS server on the storage server. But there is multiple network file systems out there with different characteristics. Please have a look at:

1. BeeGFS (Parallel networked filesystem)
2. NFS (oldschool "network file system")
3. Lustre (Parallel networked filesystem)
4. CIFS/Samba (More often used to "share files" among workstations)

But if you´re not used to this kind of stuff I would recommend to have a loo at BeeGFS or NFS. NFS have support of of the box in *nix operating systems and BeeGFS should be pretty easy to set up.